# Bluetooth Related Linker Errors in XCode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I'm relatively new to iOS development. I'm not sure what to do about resolving the following errors that I believe are due to referencing a bluetooth library. What can I do to debug/fix this?

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey", referenced from:
      _nclSStartScan in libNCLiOS.a(nclCb.o)
  "_CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey", referenced from:
      -[Boss centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:] in libNCLiOS.a(nclCb.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBUUID", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libNCLiOS.a(nclCb.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBCentralManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libNCLiOS.a(nclCb.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Have you added the Core Bluetooth framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't done Bluetooth related development on IOS but the messages might be related to the missing Bluetooth framework in the project files.
Have you added them ?
IOBluetooth.framework
IOBluetoothUI.framework

Comment: I hate to say this, but I'm finding it hard to determine how to check/achieve that. It was something I thought of at first, but it wasn't clear to me how that works at all.

Comment: Ah I found out how. If you go to the root app file and click on it, there is something called "Link Binary With Libraries". I needed CoreBluetooth.Framework.